# Text in cell with URL hidden

Tags: macos, numbers

I'm trying to copy and paste a number (tracking number) from a UPS notification into a cell on Numbers.  I want the number to appear with the link hidden but it keeps pasting the entire URL in the cell.  Excel did this for me and I am new to numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `HYPERLINK()` function.

`HYPERLINK(url,link-text)`

The first parameter is the `URL` as a string in quotes, the second is the tracking number as a string also in quotes.

From the documentation:

> **HYPERLINK**
>
> The HYPERLINK function creates a clickable link that opens a webpage
>   or new email message.
>
> HYPERLINK(url, link-text) url: A standard universal resource locator.
>   url is a string value that must contain a properly formatted universal
>   resource locator string.
>
> link-text: An optional string value that specifies the text that
>   appears as a clickable link in the cell. If link-text is omitted, url
>   is used as link-text.
>
> **Examples**
>   `=HYPERLINK(“http://www.apple.com”, “Apple”)` creates a link with the text Apple that, when clicked, opens the default web browser to the
>   Apple homepage.
>
> `=HYPERLINK(“mailto:janedoe@example.com?subject=Quote Request”, “Get Quote”)` creates a link with the text Get Quote that, when clicked,
>   opens the default email application and addresses a new message to
>   janedoe@example.com with the subject line Quote Request.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use "copy link" when copying the tracking number. Instead use the text copy (cmd-c) command. If you do so, the number will be pasted, not the underlying link.

Comment: The OP states "I want the number to appear with the link hidden", so how does your answer fulfill this?

Comment: I may have misunderstood "the link hidden" as "without the url link" instead of "with the url linked to (the number)", if that is what the OP wants.